# Gui Library in Python

Tags: python

I am in need of making an interface for Automata Construction. For those who are unaware of what an automata is, I basically need circles and arrows, extending them on the user interface and then various text to describe it. For example :- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DFAexample.svg

I was wondering if there is any advanced library in Python which could let me do all of this. Please give me suggestions. I plan to use lots of internal frames and showing parsing of strings diagramatically .  I had planned to use jython to use the swing libraries but I would like to know if there any other suggestions that I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used PyQt4 to produce something like this:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/graphicsview-diagramscene.html

which is the C++ version. Draw boxes, draw arrows, drag them around and so forth. Actually I think I pretty much ported the C++ version line-by-line to Python. Or someone else did.

Answer (score 1):

[PySide](http://www.pyside.org/) (Qt), [WxPython](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WxPython), [PyGtk](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyGtk)

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your picture and have another one idea - you can use [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) and [pydot](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/).